# How to send the object into the Scala view

Tags: html, object, playframework-2.0

How to send the object into the Scala view

I have written these files, and when im trying to build them I getting this error, that is described in the bottom

app/views/timeline/index.scala.html

```
@(token: models.Token)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello Mr @{token.name}
  </body>
</html>
```

apps/controllers/TimeLine.java

```
public class TimeLine extends Controller {
    public static Result index() {

        Token token = new Token();
        token.name("NInjaaa");

        return ok(views.html.timeline.index.render(token)); //I dont know how to send it...

    }
}
```

app/models/Token.java

```
package models;

import play.db.ebean.Model;

public class Token extends Model{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5629541435986605754L;
    public String name;

}
```

Getting this error message when compiling

```
[error] /Users/fbranchetti/Dropbox/webproject/timeline/app/controllers/TimeLine.java:17: cannot find symbol
[error] symbol  : method name(java.lang.String)
[error] location: class models.Token
[error]             token.name("NInjaaa");
[error]                  ^
[error] /Users/fbranchetti/Dropbox/webproject/timeline/app/controllers/TimeLine.java:18: render() in views.html.timeline.index cannot be applied to (models.Token)
[error]             return ok(views.html.timeline.index.render(token));
[error]                                                ^
[error] 2 errors
[error] {file:/Users/fbranchetti/Dropbox/webproject/timeline/}TimeLine/compile:compile: javac returned nonzero exit code
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's mistake in your question, but your `Token` model should be placed exactly in file

`/app/models/Token.java`

then it will be available by default to all views. In other case you need to specify whole path to the class, including packages.

```
@(token: some.non.standard.package.Token)
```

**After edit:**

You don't need to write/use getters and setters for public fields of the model. Additionaly you need to pass a `token` as a param to the view which is just a Scala function

```
public static Result index() {
    Token token = new Token();
    token.name = "Ninja";
    return ok(views.html.timeline.index.render(token));
}
```

Comment: It complaints now because I dont have a setter and getter.

Comment: Och I rewrote your mistake, it should be: `token.name = "Some String";`